# What is the role of imperative form in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, conjugations, causation

> 「ケガはないかい?」ハリーを引っ張り上げて**立たせ**ながらケンタウルスが声をかけた。

Please help me understand why they used imperative form (立たせ) in this sentence. I thought it is only used to give out order, request... and rarely used in writing language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This 立たせ isn't imperative form but causative. 立たせろ is imperative form of causative. 立たせる is causative and it means "to make someone stand".

Comment: So causative from drop its る when it is used with ながら ?

Comment: Causative verbs became 連用形(continuous form) before this usage of ながら. It is 立たせ in the case of 立たせる.